# Shallow nested routes still looking for id of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested

Relatively new to Ruby on Rails but I think I have the basics down. I'm running into one problem though that i just can't figure out and don't really know how to debug.

I have shallow routes:

```
resources :incident_reports, :shallow => true do
    get :thanks, :on => :collection
    get :monthly_totals, :on => :collection
    post :monthly_totals_download, :on => :collection
    resources :supervisory_reviews, :comments
  end
```

And rake routes shows what i expect:

```
incident_report_supervisory_reviews GET    /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/supervisory_reviews(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                                         POST   /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/supervisory_reviews(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
  new_incident_report_supervisory_review GET    /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/supervisory_reviews/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                 edit_supervisory_review GET    /supervisory_reviews/:id/edit(.:format)                                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                      supervisory_review GET    /supervisory_reviews/:id(.:format)                                      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                                         PUT    /supervisory_reviews/:id(.:format)                                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                                         DELETE /supervisory_reviews/:id(.:format)                                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"supervisory_reviews"}
                incident_report_comments GET    /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/comments(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                                         POST   /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/comments(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
             new_incident_report_comment GET    /incident_reports/:incident_report_id/comments/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
                            edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
                                 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                                         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                                         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                                                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
```

i have show and update and everything else defined in supervisory_reviews_controller

```
def update
    @supervisory_review = SupervisoryReview.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @supervisory_review.update_attributes(params[:supervisory_review])
        format.html { redirect_to(@supervisory_review.incident_report, :notice => 'Supervisory review was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(@supervisory_review.incident_report, :notice => 'An error occurred.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @supervisory_review.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

but when i try to show, update or delete a supervisory review 
(form example)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/supervisory_reviews/1047" class="edit_supervisory_review" id="edit_supervisory_review_1047" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ii8Xhygfcr71icNZfljlEkQItpV1+zFKaEn6ZZdYjiE=" />
```

(looks right, right?)

i get "The page you were looking for doesn't exist"

and the log says:

> Started POST
>   "/supervisory_reviews/1047" for
>   10.1.5.24 at Fri Jun 24 17:14:21 -0 400 2011   Processing by
>   SupervisoryReviewsController#update as
>   HTML   Parameters:
>   {"authenticity_token"=>"ii8Xhygfcr71icNZfljlEkQItpV1+zFKaEn6ZZdYji
>   E=", "utf8"=>"âo"", "id"=>"1047",
>   "supervisory_review"=>{"inappropriate_reason"=
>
> > "", "advocacy_next_steps"=>"", "resolution"=>"",
> >     "comments"=>"gfhsdfgsdfg", "ha
> >     ndling_of_incident"=>"",
> >     "recommendations"=>"dfsgdfggdfsd",
> >     "need_for_advocacy"=
> >     "false", "incident_resolved"=>"true", "incident_handled_appropriately"=>"true"}
> >     } Completed   in 2ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't
>   find IncidentReport without an ID):
>   lib/role_requirement_system.rb:121:in
>   `check_roles'
>
>   lib/role_requirement_system.rb:121:in`
>   check_roles'

so why is it looking for an IncidentReport?

the weirdest part is Comments work fine and as far as i can tell, the code for both resources is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the routes but with the lib/role_requirement_system.rb line 121. Perhaps that code needs an IncidentReport to provide authorization. Post the code from that library if you need more help.